# Padding from two elements overlapping

Tags: html, css

When I add padding to a block element, it overlaps with other elements' padding. Here's the code.

```
<section class="hero">
        <h1>Studying REDEFINED</h1>
        <p>Learn, review, and analyse. Do more with less.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="studying">
        <h2><a class="stages" href="learn.html">Learn.</a> <span style="color: #7daca8;">></span> <a class="stages" href="review.html">Review.</a></h2>
    </section>
```

Comment: There is no added padding in your code.

Comment: Please explain little more.. what the main problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- i think that you give this padding to inline elements like `a, span` but because of those is inline elements they are should to overlap each other the solution is to change the inline display of those elements to another inline display like `inline-table`

> Example

```
span , a {
  display: inline-table;
  padding: 25px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question mark it as true